# Return blank with IFERROR

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel sheet, I am looking up for some values and if it is not present I want to replace it by blank space. My code works fine when I replace `iferror` with `0`. However, when I try to replace it with a blank space `""` I get the error -

```
Run time error:"1004"  

Application-defined or Object-defined error
```

Here is my code -

```
        Cells(9, 8) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Roll '#]],Sheet3!C15:K78,9,0), "")"
```

Why does the above code work with `0` but not `""`?

Comment: What do you mean by replacing of `iferror` with `0`? Do you want returning "" in case of no match?

Comment: if there is any error or na value it will be replaced by 0.

Comment: Then, you must use """" instead of ""... In fact, see the answer which has been posted.

Comment: Using `""` vs `""""` is not a typo as someone tried to close this question as such. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pad the double quotes.

```
Cells(9, X) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Roll '#]],Sheet3!C15:K78,9,0), """")"
```